# cant pull image from own private docker repo

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I can't seem to pull from my own private repo on dockerhub. I successfully pushed the image to dockerhub (using macosx) and set it to private. I then tried to pull from another laptop (Windows 10) but I keep getting `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for {username}/{repo}, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

I am using a command like, `docker pull {username}/{reponame}:{tag}`. The windows laptop is a work laptop and the macosx is the personal computer. Does it have to do something with a transparent proxy? I looked into this, [control docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) but I don't know how to set that up in Windows; the article instructs for a unix based system it seems.

I also tried adding the registry name (based on other stackoverflow posts) in the front like, `docker pull hub.docker.com/{username}/{reponame}:{tag}` but that gives me another error:
`Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 408 response body: invalid character '<' ...`

I ensured I am logged in:

```
docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you paste the result of nslookup -type=A auth.docker.io and nslookup -type=AAAA auth.docker.io both with IPv6 enabled and disabled?

Comment: ```Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    auth.docker.io
Addresses:  18.232.227.119
          23.22.155.84
          34.195.246.183
          52.4.20.24
          35.174.73.84
          52.5.11.128
          52.72.232.213
          54.236.165.68```

Comment: ```nslookup -type=AAAA auth.docker.io
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    auth.docker.io```

Comment: That was with the IPv6 enabled; when I disabled within the WiFi properties tab (and restarted); I got the same response

Comment: If you are using Mac, please ensure to allow Unrestriction Access to Web Content

Comment: Here is the tutorial to set Web Content on mac: https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/mchlbcf0dfe2/mac

Comment: thanks for suggestions. im trying to pull from windows 10; the mac seems to push/pull just fine. I did look at that solution; i commented on the bottom asking the OP for assistance as well, lol.

Comment: Just set Web Content to Unrestricted Access